# How to replace credentials and other secrets when building locally with Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I want to keep credentials and other secrets out of my git repository. For various reasons (I'm working on a forked GitHub repository), the credentials are stored in a class, not in a config file.

For building on Microsoft App center, I'm successfully replacing the credentials with environment variables using the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Updating user settings..."
SettingsFile=$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/Client/MyApp/Helpers/UserSettings.cs

sed -i '' "s/APPCENTER_MICROSOFT/$APPCENTER_MICROSOFT/g" $SettingsFile
sed -i '' "s/APPCENTER_ANDROID/$APPCENTER_ANDROID/g" $SettingsFile
sed -i '' "s/APPCENTER_IOS/$APPCENTER_IOS/g" $SettingsFile

echo "Updating cloud service settings..."
CloudServiceFile=$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/Client/MyApp/Services/SurveyCloudService.cs
sed -i '' "s/APP_NAME_REPLACE/$APP_NAME_REPLACE/g" $CloudServiceFile

echo "Settings updated"
```

The problem that I have now is that I also need to make these substitutions when testing locally. Can I use build events to replace the tokens without permanently modifying the source files (perhaps using a .bat file added to .gitignore), or is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:** My current solution to this is to save the credentials by making changes to the files and then using `git stash save credentials` to track the changes. Then if I need to build locally I can apply the changes using `git stash list` and `git stash apply stash@{<n>}`. Once I'm done testing and debugging I can use `git reset --hard` to remove the credentials. It works, but there must be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant solution would be to have separate directories for your source tree and your local testing environment.  For example you might create a `target/` or `dist/` directory, which would be either outside the git worktree or excluded by `.gitignore`.

The build process's job is to populate the local environment based on what's in the source tree (and possibly other information, such as environment variables).  So then swapping in the appropriate credentials becomes a step in the build process, no different from how your production (and/or production-like) environments would be built.  Because the changes are applied to a copy that isn't checked in, you don't have to worry about rolling them back (or, worse, accidentally committing *without* rolling them back and exposing your sensitive data in a basically irreversible way).